# How do I get jquery to select classes in html which has been loaded using client.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In my html document I have this code

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '(URL)example.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
       var theblog = client.responseText;
       $("#bloglocation").html(theblog);
}
client.send();
});
```

In that loaded html I have

```
    <p class="example">example</p>
```

Later on in the file I use jquery to change to color of all the elements in the class example.

```
    $('.example).css({"background-color" : "yellow"});
```

The jquery works for all the elements with that class that are not in the loaded html. How can I get it to work for the class in the loaded html.

Comment: call it once your dynamic elements are added in the DOM, not before

Comment: @roasted It's called at the very end of the html document. Is that what you mean?

Comment: but ajax is asynchronous, so set your code inside callback of ajax once you have added targeted elements, i mean after this line: `$("#bloglocation").html(theblog);`

Comment: much obliged. Works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery, so use jQuery:

```
$.get('example.txt').done(function(data) {
    $("#bloglocation").html(data);
});
```

But you need to set the background color after the data has loaded:

```
$.get('example.txt').done(function(data) {
    $("#bloglocation").html(data);
    $("#bloglocation .example").css({"background-color" : "yellow"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An XMLHttpRequest is an asynchronous operation, meaning the rest of your code is running while that AJAX request is made.

You could repeat your code in the onreadystatechange

```
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
   var theblog = client.responseText;
   $("#bloglocation").html(theblog);
   $('.example').css({"background-color" : "yellow"});
}
```

that way the CSS is updated after the AJAX request finishes.